# Expo, eas: Wrong accounts are shown for the currently logged in user

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I `eas logout` (from `userA`), then `eas login` (into `userB`).

I still see accounts associated with `userA` when I run `eas whomai`.

Therefore I cannot perform a build for userB, or any other operations for userB

**Reproducible demo**

```
% eas whoami
userA

Accounts:
• account1_userA (Role: Owner)
• account2_userA (Role: Developer)

% eas logout
Logged out

% eas login

Log in to EAS with email or username (exit and run eas login for other options)
✔ Email or username … userB
✔ Password … ***
Logged in

% eas whoami
userA

Accounts:
• account1_userA (Role: Owner)
• account2_userA (Role: Developer)
```

**Environment**

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 14.1
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 21.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 10.2.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.14.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.11005911
Xcode: 15.0.1/15A507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ~49.0.15 => 49.0.21
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.72.6 => 0.72.6
react-native-web: ~0.19.6 => 0.19.9
npmGlobalPackages:
eas-cli: 5.9.3
Expo Workflow: bare
```

**Error output**

```
You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.

Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[qqweqwqe-qwqwe-qweqwe-qwewe-qweqweqweqwew] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[qweqweqw-qweqwe-qwewqe-qweqwe-qweqweqweqweqwe], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1)
Request ID: fad2a51c-6d03-4b27-89b3-afa07ff9ac98
```